# Asymptotic and continuity of function

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I'm working with asymptotic relation and would like to proof this theorem

**Theorem:**
Let $f$ and $g$ functions with $f\sim g$ when $x\to x_0$. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=l\in\mathbb{R}$. Let be $h$ a function continuous at $l$ with $h(l)\neq 0$, then $h(f(x))\sim h(g(x))$.

**Proof:**
Here is my attempt: $f\sim g$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=l$ implies that $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)=l$ too. We calculate:

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{h(f(x))}{h(g(x))}$$

By continuity of $h$ we have:

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{h(f(x))}{h(g(x))}=\dfrac{h(l)}{h(l)}=1$$

This is equivalent to the thesis:

$h(f(x))\sim h(g(x))$

Do you think that this is correct ?

Thank you all for your replies.

Comment: Your statements of the form "$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}=\cdots$" make no sense: limits of what?? It's as meaningful as writing something like "$\sqrt{\phantom{5}}=x+y$".

Comment: Thanks, the "=" were placed wrong